# Render an mesh topmost

Tags: c#, rendering, sharpdx

I can render anything 3d with SharpDX. However, my mind is mixed what should I do to render a mesh topmost. (Example: menu and all things behind). How can I render something front of the all other meshes even I do many transforms rotations etc.

Comment: Usually you'd render it last, after doing one of the following three things to ignore the previous depth: A) clear the depth buffer, B) disable Z-Test, or C) clamp all vertices to the near plane in your vertex shader. There's a few other ways, depending on exactly what you're doing - can you describe your situation, and whether any of the above might be suitable for your needs?

Comment: Think I pasted a secondary layer on window and I do same 3d operations and also I have layer at background. (Just like in photoshop).

Comment: It sounds like clearing the depth buffer before rendering your topmost object is your best bet, if you still want to be able to work with the object 3-dimensionally (the other two options I mentioned work for flat objects, but can cause ordering or z-fighting when used with more complex 3D objects, like layered or non-convex meshes) Would that approach suit your case?

Comment: I did it like : After DepthStencilStateDescription for my first layer                 context.OutputMerger.DepthStencilState = null; and for my topmost layer                 context.OutputMerger.SetDepthStencilState(DSState); I am not sure if I did it correctly. Anyway that worked.

Comment: If it worked for you, it sounds good. :) Feel free to post your solution as an answer so it can help other users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

First up I would make a render state helper class to make it easy to work with blend, depth, raster and sampler states.

```
Friend Class StateHelper
Friend Shared Function [New](ByVal device As Device, ByVal sourceBlend As BlendOption, ByVal destinationBlend As BlendOption) As BlendState
    Dim description As BlendStateDescription = BlendStateDescription.Default
    description.RenderTarget(0).IsBlendEnabled = True
    description.RenderTarget(0).SourceBlend = sourceBlend
    description.RenderTarget(0).DestinationBlend = destinationBlend
    description.RenderTarget(0).SourceAlphaBlend = sourceBlend
    description.RenderTarget(0).DestinationAlphaBlend = destinationBlend
    Return New BlendState(device, description)
End Function

Friend Shared Function [New](ByVal device As Device) As BlendState
    Dim description As BlendStateDescription = BlendStateDescription.Default
    description.RenderTarget(0).IsBlendEnabled = False
    description.RenderTarget(0).RenderTargetWriteMask = ColorWriteMaskFlags.Alpha
    Return New BlendState(device, description)
End Function


Friend Shared Function [New](ByVal device As Device, ByVal sourceBlend As BlendOption, ByVal destinationBlend As BlendOption, ByVal sourceBlend2 As BlendOption, ByVal destinationBlend2 As BlendOption) As BlendState
    Dim description As BlendStateDescription = BlendStateDescription.Default
    description.IndependentBlendEnable = True
    description.RenderTarget(0).IsBlendEnabled = True
    description.RenderTarget(0).SourceBlend = sourceBlend
    description.RenderTarget(0).DestinationBlend = destinationBlend
    description.RenderTarget(0).SourceAlphaBlend = sourceBlend
    description.RenderTarget(0).DestinationAlphaBlend = destinationBlend
    description.RenderTarget(1).IsBlendEnabled = True
    description.RenderTarget(1).SourceBlend = sourceBlend2
    description.RenderTarget(1).DestinationBlend = destinationBlend2
    description.RenderTarget(1).SourceAlphaBlend = sourceBlend2
    description.RenderTarget(1).DestinationAlphaBlend = destinationBlend2
    Return New BlendState(device, description)
End Function
Friend Shared Function [New](ByVal device As Device, ByVal mode As CullMode) As RasterizerState
    Dim description As RasterizerStateDescription = RasterizerStateDescription.Default
    description.CullMode = mode
    Dim state As RasterizerState = New RasterizerState(device, description)
    Return state
End Function
Public Shared Function [New](ByVal device As Device, ByVal description As RasterizerStateDescription) As RasterizerState
    Return New RasterizerState(device, description)
End Function
Public Shared Function [New](ByVal device As Device, ByVal description As DepthStencilStateDescription) As DepthStencilState
    Return New DepthStencilState(device, description)
End Function
Friend Shared Function [New](ByVal device As Device, ByVal depthEnable As Boolean, ByVal depthWriteEnable As Boolean) As DepthStencilState
    Dim description As DepthStencilStateDescription = DepthStencilStateDescription.Default
    description.IsDepthEnabled = depthEnable
    description.DepthWriteMask = If(depthWriteEnable, DepthWriteMask.All, DepthWriteMask.Zero)
    Dim state As New DepthStencilState(device, description)
    Return state
End Function
Friend Shared Function [New](ByVal device As Device, ByVal filterMode As Filter, ByVal uvwMode As TextureAddressMode) As SamplerState
    Dim description As SamplerStateDescription = SamplerStateDescription.Default
    description.Filter = filterMode
    description.AddressU = uvwMode
    description.AddressV = uvwMode
    description.AddressW = uvwMode
    description.BorderColor = Color.Black
    Return New SamplerState(device, description)
End Function
End Class
Public NotInheritable Class RenderStates
Public Sub New(ByVal device As Device)
    Me.Additive = StateHelper.[New](device, BlendOption.SourceAlpha, BlendOption.One)
    Me.AlphaBlend = StateHelper.[New](device, BlendOption.One, BlendOption.InverseSourceAlpha)
    Me.NonPremultiplied = StateHelper.[New](device, BlendOption.SourceAlpha, BlendOption.InverseSourceAlpha)
    Me.Opaque = StateHelper.[New](device, BlendOption.One, BlendOption.Zero)
    Me.NoColorWrits = StateHelper.[New](device)

    Me.AdditiveParticle = StateHelper.[New](device, BlendOption.SourceAlpha, BlendOption.One, BlendOption.One, BlendOption.InverseSourceAlpha)
    Me.AlphaBlendParticle = StateHelper.[New](device, BlendOption.One, BlendOption.InverseSourceAlpha, BlendOption.SourceAlpha, BlendOption.One)
    Me.NonPremultipliedParticle = StateHelper.[New](device, BlendOption.SourceAlpha, BlendOption.InverseSourceAlpha, BlendOption.SourceAlpha, BlendOption.One)

    Me.CullFront = StateHelper.[New](device, CullMode.Front)
    Me.CullBack = StateHelper.[New](device, CullMode.Back)
    Me.CullNone = StateHelper.[New](device, CullMode.None)
    Dim description As RasterizerStateDescription = Me.CullBack.Description
    description.FillMode = FillMode.Wireframe
    Me.WireFrame = StateHelper.[New](device, description)
    description.CullMode = CullMode.None
    Me.WireFrameCullNone = StateHelper.[New](device, description)

    Me.Default = StateHelper.[New](device, True, True)
    Me.DepthRead = StateHelper.[New](device, True, False)
    Me.None = StateHelper.[New](device, False, False)

    Me.PointWrap = StateHelper.[New](device, Filter.MinMagMipPoint, TextureAddressMode.Wrap)
    Me.PointClamp = StateHelper.[New](device, Filter.MinMagMipPoint, TextureAddressMode.Clamp)
    Me.PointBorder = StateHelper.[New](device, Filter.MinMagMipPoint, TextureAddressMode.Border)
    Me.PointMirror = StateHelper.[New](device, Filter.MinMagMipPoint, TextureAddressMode.Mirror)
    Me.LinearWrap = StateHelper.[New](device, Filter.MinMagMipLinear, TextureAddressMode.Wrap)
    Me.LinearClamp = StateHelper.[New](device, Filter.MinMagMipLinear, TextureAddressMode.Clamp)
    Me.LinearBorder = StateHelper.[New](device, Filter.MinMagMipLinear, TextureAddressMode.Border)
    Me.LinearMirror = StateHelper.[New](device, Filter.MinMagMipLinear, TextureAddressMode.Mirror)
    Me.AnisotropicWrap = StateHelper.[New](device, Filter.Anisotropic, TextureAddressMode.Wrap)
    Me.AnisotropicClamp = StateHelper.[New](device, Filter.Anisotropic, TextureAddressMode.Clamp)
    Me.AnisotropicMirror = StateHelper.[New](device, Filter.Anisotropic, TextureAddressMode.Mirror)
    Me.BorderLin = StateHelper.[New](device, Filter.MinMagMipLinear, TextureAddressMode.Border)

End Sub
' Fields
Public ReadOnly Additive As BlendState
Public ReadOnly AlphaBlend As BlendState
Public ReadOnly NonPremultiplied As BlendState
Public ReadOnly Opaque As BlendState
Public ReadOnly NoColorWrits As BlendState

Public ReadOnly AdditiveParticle As BlendState
Public ReadOnly AlphaBlendParticle As BlendState
Public ReadOnly NonPremultipliedParticle As BlendState

' Fields
Public ReadOnly CullBack As RasterizerState
Public ReadOnly CullFront As RasterizerState
Public ReadOnly CullNone As RasterizerState
Public ReadOnly WireFrame As RasterizerState
Public ReadOnly WireFrameCullNone As RasterizerState
' Fields
Public ReadOnly [Default] As DepthStencilState
Public ReadOnly DepthRead As DepthStencilState
Public ReadOnly None As DepthStencilState
' Fields
Public ReadOnly AnisotropicClamp As SamplerState
Public ReadOnly AnisotropicMirror As SamplerState
Public ReadOnly AnisotropicWrap As SamplerState
Public ReadOnly LinearClamp As SamplerState
Public ReadOnly LinearBorder As SamplerState
Public ReadOnly LinearMirror As SamplerState
Public ReadOnly LinearWrap As SamplerState
Public ReadOnly PointClamp As SamplerState
Public ReadOnly PointBorder As SamplerState
Public ReadOnly PointMirror As SamplerState
Public ReadOnly PointWrap As SamplerState

Public ReadOnly BorderLin As SamplerState

End Class
```

Next when its time to draw you do it like this

```
 ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetTargets(_device.DepthStencilView, ColorBufferRT)
 ImmediateContext.ClearRenderTargetView(ColorBufferRT, New Color4(0, 0, 0, 0))
 ImmediateContext.ClearDepthStencilView(DepthStencilView, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1, 0)
 ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.SetViewport(Viewport)

   //Set render states
 ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.BlendState = device.RenderStates.Opaque // Change as needed
 ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.State = device.RenderStates.CullNone // Change as needed
 ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetDepthStencilState(device.RenderStates.Default) // Change as needed

//Draw 3D stuff here in back to front or front to back depending on your alpha requirements 



// Set 2d Depthstate to none or clear the depthbuffer
ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetDepthStencilState(device.RenderStates.None)

ImmediateContext.ClearDepthStencilView(DepthStencilView, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1, 0)

 ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.BlendState = device.RenderStates.AlphaBlend// Change as needed
 ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.State = device.RenderStates.CullNone // Change as needed

 // Draw Top most stuff here Like Menu\Hud
 UI.Draw(ImmediateContext)
```

I use the SharpDX.Toolkit.Spritebatch to do all my 2d drawing as it handles batching and depthlayers for me and allows to get the draw calls for my UI
down to 5(Alpha, Additive, Opaque, Font0, Font1) draw calls not matter the amount of UI I have because I also use a spritesheet.

Here is a call to spritebatch.draw where last value on each line is the layer I want it to be in.

```
 SpriteBatch.Begin(Toolkit.Graphics.SpriteSortMode.Deferred, GraphicsDevice.BlendStates.AlphaBlend, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, ViewMatrix)
SpriteBatch.Draw(UISpritesheet, destrect, sourcerect, UINode.Settings.Color, 0, Nothing, Nothing, 0.5)
SpriteBatch.Draw(UISpritesheet, destrect, sourcerect, UINode.Settings.Color, 0, Nothing, Nothing, 0.0)
SpriteBatch.Draw(UISpritesheet, destrect, sourcerect, UINode.Settings.Color, 0, Nothing, Nothing, 1)
SpriteBatch.End
```

You can find an up to date ToolKit on my GitHub page, you will also need the custom build of sharpDX to use it, you will find that on my GitHub too.

Answer (score -1):

That can be something like:

```
RenderLoop.Run(form, () =>
            {

//...
                context.ClearDepthStencilView(depthView, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1.0f, 0);                    
                context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderView, Color.Black);
//render any mesh

//...

//render on secondary layer:
                            context.ClearDepthStencilView(depthView, DepthStencilClearFlags.Depth, 1.0f, 0);


                menu1.VerticesBuffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer.Create(device, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, menu1.Vertices);
                menu1.Render(); context.Draw(menu1.VerticesCount, 0);
                // Present!
                swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);
});
```

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it, read DMGregory comment about clearing the dpethbuffer then drawing the UI. Its the correct way to do it its how I do it and its how you should do it. You proly wont have an issues with one simple mesh drawn without a DepthStencilState. You should also have a class of all the pre built types of DepthStencilState. DepthRead, DepthWrite and the default depth state. Have both layers set to default depth then just clear your depth buffer before you want to draw your UI and once before your draw your other mesh data.

Answer (score -1):

Imho one should **always** render in front to back order, unless there are transparent objects in front. And **not** clear the depth buffer too lightfootedly.

Render the close things (those that occupy a relevant part of the screen space) first and do a depth write accordingly (either by default or by tweaking with a shader). If rendering a closeby object last, there will be **redundant rendering** that will in any case be covered by the big thing in front.

If for example rendering a menu texture (a screen quad of two triangles) that covers a lot of the screen, do it **first** of all, using a shader where you have in the pixel shader part something like:

```
struct PS_OUTPUT {
    float4 Color      : COLOR0;
    float Depth       : DEPTH0;
    };
```

and

```
PS_OUTPUT PS_Main(VS_OUTPUT input) {
    PS_OUTPUT output;
    [calculate res]
    output.Color = res;
    output.Depth = 0;
    return output;
    }
```

and

```
technique FullscreenTech
    {
    pass FullscreenPass0
        {
        blabla
        ZWriteEnable = True;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if the menu is transparent? By rendering it first you will not get correct blending. It should be rendered last. All 3d drawing should be done first in a frame and then the 2d parts.

Comment: Well i did write __unless there are transparent objects in front__, 1st sentence. But i cannot agree with you on the paint order. If you for example have a HUD mask, there is absolutely point in rendering underneath it. Same with menu surfaces, but indeed you are right in that transparent surfaces need a back to front order.

Comment: How did I not see that on the first time, I did read it like 6 times too... Sorry.

Comment: Np :-). I recommend all and everyone to consider the paint order once in a while; for example rendering the skybox first (if anyone uses such) is n00bish. The GPU is hugely efficient at clipping pixels behind. (I wonder why my answer is downvoted to -1, it is most certainly the correct answer. Maybe if my nickname was Philip or something.... :-))